# Find $\lim_{x \to \infty} (-1)^{x-1}\sin(\pi\sqrt{x^2+0.5x+1})$ with $x\in\mathbb{N}$

Tags: calculus, limits, limits-without-lhopital

> Evaluate
>   $$\lim_{x \to \infty} (-1)^{x-1}\sin(\pi\sqrt{x^2+0.5x+1})$$
>   where $x$ belongs to the natural numbers.

Guys, this is what I have done:
I first took $x$ out of root and in this process I took $0.5/x$ and $1/x$ as zero, so now I have $\sin(\pi x)$.
We know that $\sin(\pi x)=0$ for $x$ belonging to natural numbers
so answer must be zero, but the answer is given as $-\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}$.
I don't know what's wrong in my procedure.

Comment: I don't think there's a valid answer. The function keeps alternating without converging to a finite value...

Comment: You need to typeset your question and tell us where you are stuck. You can read here on how to ask a question https://math.stackexchange.com/help/notation

Comment: Check your text again, you probably forgot something in the expression, because the result is wrong

Comment: I think it's zero, since the argument in the sine will "behave" as $n*\pi$ as $n$ tends to $\infty$

Comment: no,the question is absolutely correct

Comment: Okay I think there is a way in which that answer would make sense. You can reduce the expression inside the square root to $(x+\frac{1}{4})^2+\frac{15}{16}$ so maybe, for x big $\pi\sqrt{x^2+0.5x+1}\approx\pi(x+\frac{1}{4})$ and then for x even and for x odd you have $(-1)^{x-1}\sin(\pi x +\frac{\pi}{4})=-\frac{1}{\sqrt 2}$. This isn't a proof, but maybe it's a hint.

Comment: Oh ,I got it ... Thank you!!

Answer (score 3):

Note that 
$$\sqrt{x^2+0.5x+1}-x=\frac{0.5x+1}{\sqrt{x^2+0.5x+1}+x}$$
Then, if $x$ is an integer, recalling that $\sin(t-x\pi)=(-1)^x\sin(t)$, it follows that
$$(-1)^{x-1}\sin(\pi\sqrt{x^2+0.5x+1})=-\sin(\pi\sqrt{x^2+0.5x+1}-\pi x)\\=
 - \sin\left(\frac{\pi(0.5x+1)}{\sqrt{x^2+0.5x+1}+x}\right).$$
Can you take it from here?

Answer (score 0):

This question can be solved in another way too.

We see that we have $\sqrt(x^2+0.5x+1)$ in the argument of sin function. Now clearly the given quadratic equation is positive for any value of 'x' because the D(determinant) value is always negative. So for any value of positive x this equation doesn't have any real solution. Now also we know that the value of sinx can never be greater than 1. So the argument inside the sin value is a very large positive value(as x tends to infinity) which gives the sin() value equal to 1(i.e as $x\to \infty sin(\pi\sqrt(x^2+0.5x+1))$ will tend to 1).Now the entire limiting value depend on $(-1)^(x-1)$ or $-(-1)^x$. This is a type of indeterminant form so this can be solved using L'Hospital's rule.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. It is in your best interest that you use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Comment: No, the value of the sine function does not tend to 1

Comment: maximum value of sine function is 1 so it will tend to 1 when the argument value is very large.Since sine function is monotonically an increasing function for positive value of the argument.

Comment: MathJaxing your post made it so pretty wonderful, that I could not resist the urge of voting it up. :-)

Comment: @3251_ali what?! Sine is not monotonic!

Comment: Sine function is monotonic for a given range. And according to the given question the argument is always positive irrespective of the value of x so the value of sine tends to 1.

Comment: You are wrong, sine function is oscillating for $x\to+\infty$